# Ember.js run function on route change for every single route. Global activate function?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using the MathJax library which lets you have latex on the page, but it only runs if you visit the route from a `<a>`. If you visit from a `{{link-to}}` helper, it won't run it's typesetting function because the page isn't actually reloading.

I've been able to work around this by putting this in every route:

```
  activate () {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
      MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, document.body]);
    });
  }
```

but I'm curious if there's a global activate function I can overwrite/extend instead to avoid having to put this statement on every single page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may create a mixin (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html):

```
//app/mixins/base-route.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  activate () {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function() {
      MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, document.body]);
    });
  }
});

//app/routes/some.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import RouteMixin from '../mixins/base-route';

export default Ember.Route.extend(RouteMixin, {});
```

Or try to use reopen (http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/object-model/reopening-classes-and-instances/)